# Transparent background color not working on mobile devices

Tags: php, css, wordpress, rgba

On desktop we have a transparent header and footer working fine, you can see the background image: https://www.ontarioslakecountry.com/

However, once we go into mobile on a iOS or Android device, it shows as solid and not transparent.

```css
.site-header { background-color: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5); background: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5); color: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5); }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share the CSS code here that is relevant?

Comment: .site-header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5);
    background: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5);
    color: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5);
}

Comment: Can you edit the relevant CSS (and potentially HTML if required) into the question itself please.

Comment: I have added the code into the original post.

Answer (score 0):

RGBA has somewhat limited support on mobile browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

There are some techniques for providing fallbacks to browsers that cannot deal with the rgba values. I noticed in your site header, you have css `background-color` and `background` properties both using the same value.

One approach is to use two different `background` rules with the first one set the value to a `rgb` value that non-supporting browsers will use as a fallback:

```
background: rgb(0, 84, 166); /* fallback color */
background: rgba(0, 84, 166, 0.5);
```

There are other approaches that use filters to try and maintain the transparency on non-supporting browsers. Here is a good article that goes into more depth: https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/